# Bash loop trough files in directory manually

Tags: bash

I have N files in my directory, I want to be able to loop through them with batches, for example for 2/3/4 files I want to execute one command. I saw something like this, but can't find it, unfortunately. I will try to explain what I want using pseudo code, for example:

```
i=0
while i<N:
  a=getFile(i)
  b=getFile(i+1)
  dosomething a
  dosomething b
  i+=2
```

Is there any way to do it in Bash? Right now I'm using regexp, but it gets one file at a time (I'm using `*.ext` because all files have one extension, so you can just loop through all files in the directory in your answer, if it's easier):

```
for j in *.ext; do   
 ...
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the same with most programming languages: loop and store items somewhere until you have enough of them:

```sh
declare -i count=0
declare -a files=()
for f in *.ext; do
  files[count]="$f"
  (( count += 1 ))
  if (( count == 2 )); then
    dosomething "${files[0]}"
    dosomething "${files[1]}"
    count=0
  fi
done
```

If you want to process your files in batches of more than 2 at a time we can also design something a bit more generic (adapt the value of `batch`):

```sh
declare -i batch=3
declare -i count=0
declare -a files=()
for f in *.ext; do
  files[count]="$f"
  (( count += 1 ))
  if (( count == batch )); then
    for (( i=0; i<batch; i++ )); do
      dosomething "${files[i]}"
    done
    count=0
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is syntactically slightly clunkier but more robust than my solution, because it only requires you to have enough memory for `count` number of array entries, and quicker because you avoid the indirection of storing everything in one array and then starting over.

Comment: Yep, I mainly wanted to show that this was about the same as in most programming languages. Yours is much more elegant.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I think I didn't explain it well enough in the question, I edited it, can you look once again into the case?

Comment: @Arzybek I modified my answer accordingly but it does not change much. Simply run `dosomething` as many times as you have files in a batch instead of just once for all. Or is there something else that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect your arguments into an array, and then slice that any way you like.

```
array=( *.ext )
for ((i=0; i<=${#array[@]}; i+=2)); do
    dosomething "${array[i]}" "${array[i+1]}"
done
```